# Java: How to get the cover image file name of a mp3 file using "Java MP3 ID3 Tag Library" or jaudiotagger

Tags: java, image, mp3

I am just programming a music player in Java, and I want the application be able to show the cover image of the track currently being played.

I have found a lot of libraries that helps with that, as for example: "Java MP3 ID3 Tag Library" or jaudiotagger.

With those two libraries, I have been able to get the cover image from the mp3 file, when the image is embeeded inside the mp3 file.

But I have found some mp3 files that point to an external .jpg image, which is the cover of that mp3, instead of having the image bytes inside the mp3 file ...

I have come to that conclusion by using MediaMonkey application, and looking at the properties of one of such mp3 then in the Artwork tab, I can see the image, and when placing the mouse pointer inside the image, a hint appears with that file name pointing to an image file in the same directory as the mp3.

I do not have any knowledge on how to extract mp3 tags, so I have not been able to get which tag the file name is stored and even less to obtain that file name.

What I am ideally looking for with this question is to know which tag that image file name is stored, and a way to obtain its value with any of the two libraries that I have checked:

"Java MP3 ID3 Tag Library" or jaudiotagger

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that the information of those extra images were not inside the mp3 files ... but only in the same directory.

I could determine that by doing the test of adding more images into one mp3 file (with MediaMonkey), and choosing to add only a link to the image, instead of attaching the image bytes into the mp3 file.
The result was that the mp3 file had not increased its size, and that a new binary file appeared at that directory (probably with the information of images of the mp3 files).

I thought that the image filename was inside the mp3 file, in any of the specific tags used for that, but no library could extract it ... and the thing was that the mp3 itself did not have any link to the image file.

So the solution I have adopted, is to read all .png and .jpg images in the mp3 directory, and choose the most accurate for the front cover image (looking for the word "front" (case insensitive) in those filenames)